# change a field value of database table on button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to change database field value on button click using PHP,HTML, Javascript?

What I need to do is, I have a list of layouts from database and displaying in a webpage. I need to add one button for each layout. When I click a button of one layout, it will be the active layout and the database field called 'active' should be changed to 1. All other value of 'active' will be 0. SO that user can select one active layout at a time.

Is there any simple way to do this? Any tutorial or example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you should use an ajax call with Jquery.

First include the jquery on your header template. Don't forget that (I always do).

Let's say that for the first active layout
you have
...
 switch one 
...

after the table you will make a

```
<script>
$("activeOne").click(
   function()
   {
      $("activeOne").fadeOut("fast",
      function()
        {
        $("activeOne").load('get_page.php?act=switch_one','',
          function() 
          {
          $("activeOne").fadeIn("fast");
           }
        );   
         }
      );
   }
);


</script>
```

I hope you understand what I'm saying.
1. for every layout you have an ID.
2. for any of that IDs you have a script that calls a get_page.php with an parameter called switch for you layout
3. now, for the php function that does that... you either check if it is inactive and you make it active  (or check if active to make inactive) ...either you send another parameter with the status you want to set.
Hope this is useful... I used exact same tehnique for exact same problem.